# how to get state of radio button and whether it is selected?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbutton

I have a group of radio buttons (matrix) and it has 4 choices. How can I find out what the selection is (programmatically) and get the BOOL of it?

Comment: The usage of NSMatrix has been deprecated as of Xcode 7.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming your matrix of radio buttons is named `matrix` and is of type `NSMatrix *`, you find the selected NSButton via NSMatrix's `selectedCell` method and then access the button's state via NSButton's `state` method, like this:

```
BOOL state = [[matrix selectedCell] state];
```

Comment: Is it possible for this call to ever return any value other than NSOnState?